# can $g(x)$ be associated to $\sum_n g(n^{-s})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, fibration

While thinking about re-constituting real symplectic manifolds into complex ones via tori fibrations and mirror symmetry I thought about a possible association of objects:

$g(x) \to \sum_n g(n^{-s})\to F(s)$

where the arrows mean the objects are corresponded, and $F(s)$ is the analytic extension of the series.

Consider the following special case:

> Is it possible to associate $g(x)=1/x$ to a complex function (a series) which sums up it's heights above the x-axis at prescribed x-values?

So this for example, would correspond $g$ to $\zeta(s)$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function.

> Then would it be possible to take the surface of revolution (hyperbola of one sheet) and associate this surface with a collection of analytic extensions of its fibers where each fiber is associated to its corresponding series?

Here each of the fibers would correspond to a copy of $\zeta(s).$ I'm wondering if these associations are kosher.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If $g$ is analytic for $|x|\le 1$ and $g(0)=0$ then $\sum_{n\ge 1} g(n^{-s})= \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \zeta(sk) $ for $\Re(s) > 1$ and similarly if $h(x)=g(1/x)$ is analytic for $|x|\le 1$ and $h(0)=0$  with $n^s$ instead of $n^{-s}$. If $g$ is analytic for $|x|< r$ with $r < 1$ then look instead at $\sum_{n\ge 2} g(n^{-s})= \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} (\zeta(sk) -1)$ for $\Re(s) > 1,|2^{-s}|< r$

Comment: @reuns I see. so there's no special correspondence between say $g(x)=1/x$ and $\sum n^{-s}$?

Comment: they are completely unrelated?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. (for $g$ analytic around $0$) there is a linear map connecting $g(x)$ with $\sum_{n\ge 2} (g(n^{-s})-g(0))$ and you can find one from the other, ie. (restricted to the correct space of Dirichlet series) there is an inverse which is linear as well.

Comment: @reuns could you please make an answer elaborating on this "linear map" connecting these objects/

Comment: @reuns could you make an answer elaborating on this linear map?